# Adding communication to a dumb 12V in-line UPS

Tags: microcontroller, usb, ethernet, ups

Edit: By "battery" I mean DC-DC UPS, I did this to avoid any confusion with an AC-AC UPS that would sit before the 12V adapter, but it seems to have caused more confusion. This DC-DC UPS is a commonly marketed as a "Mini UPS", the only inputs and outputs are two female barrel jacks for 12V in and 12V out, my plans are to modify one of these Mini UPSs to add the smarts to it, not to make a UPS from scratch.

---

I'm building a server out of a NUC-like mini PC with very low power consumption. This PC receives power from a 12V adapter and consumes 24W max. I've had issues regarding power loss, so I thought I might add an in-line battery between the wall adapter and the 12V jack to provide backup power in case of a blackout. This approach would be ok for 5 minute blackouts but sadly this is not the norm where I live, losing power for 1 hour is not that rare.

Based on this, a simple "dumb" in line UPS will not suffice, so I thought I might be able to add some smarts by attaching a low power microcontroller with USB or Ethernet support to the BMS and charge controller to fetch some info and relay that to the server. The mini-PC should be able to detect when the power is cut off from the UPS and enter hibernation, waking up when the power comes back up. My main question would be what standard protocol I could use to send that information. Some of the options I've looked into are:

1. [USB HID Power Device](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/pdcv11.pdf)
2. [NUT](https://networkupstools.org/) compatible protocol via Ethernet
3. NUT compatible protocol via USB

Option 1 would be my first choice, from what I understand it relays information to the device about the state of charge, but not much more. This could be a problem since it would be useful to be able to configure the battery pack to, for example, do a power cycle once the power comes back up. This behaviour could be hardcoded into the microcontroller, but having it do that automatically would not be ideal, as devices that don't expect this could be unexpectedly power cycled.

Option 2 seems like it would be unnecessarily complex and harder to implement on a microcontroller, however this would allow two devices on the Ethernet port to get info about the UPS without it being tied to an external device like an intermediate USB-to-NUT protocol box.

Option 3 is tempting, but it would have to be an open standard that is simple to implement, I would much appreciate suggestions regarding this.

What options you think are more viable? Any recommendations on what MCU could be used? I would also like to emphasize the low power aspect of this, for example having an SBC like a Raspberry Pi Zero handling the communication would not be an option.

Comment: basically you are trying to make a UPS. For option 1 why not put a toggle or DIP switch on the device to tell it whether to turn on when the power comes back up

Comment: I don't think asking which protocol to use for communication is very useful at this stage, if you assume you can simply parallel a 12V battery with power supply and device. You can't.

Comment: @Justme yes, I know you can't just parallel those. I'm an electronics engineer, I know a bit about how that works. I plan on modifying an already existing product that acts as an "inline UPS", adding the communication bits myself (I should probably clarify that in the question).

Comment: @user253751 a dip switch might be useful but it's better to let the connected device configure the behavior once it's ready to be told to power back down. If possible, I'd lIike it to not power cycle the device in the event of a boot failure or something similar.